# Using a 'config.php' file with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, connection

I was recently told to stop using `mysql_query()` and instead switch to `mysqli()`. Needless to say, I'm having difficulties making these changes in my code. I'd love to fix what I currently have, however I'm also looking for the most efficient (read least typing) way of looping through the example below.

In my config.php file

```
<?php
    $host = 'mysql.host.com';
    $user = 'userName';
    $password = 'password';
    $database = 'database';
    $link = new mysqli();
    $link->connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

In my index.php

```
$i = 0;
$getFundsQuery = "SELECT * FROM fund";
$getFundsResult = $link->query($getFundsQuery);
while($i < $getFundsResult->num_rows){
    echo "<option value = '".$getFundsResult['fundID']."'>".$getFundsResult['name']."</option>";
    $i++;
}
```

The immediate problem is that no data is being returned. And as stated above, I'm also looking for the method that would yield the least typing for looping through the results

Comment: By `$link ->query($getFundsQuery);` you mean `$link->query($getFundsQuery);`? Remove space

Comment: yes. However upon making that change I'm still seeing the same results, which are, unfortunately none

Comment: You have a `require "config.php"` statement?

Comment: sorry, forgot that. yes, I do have that, though I have require_once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all  you can omit the `$link->connect(..)` with:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
```

Second, loop your results like this:

```
while ( $row = $getFundsResult->fetch_object() ) {
    echo "<option value = '" . $row->fundID ."'>" . $row->name . "</option>";

}
```

Comment: that did it! Thanks! I'll give the checkmark when my time is allowed

Comment: You can't accept an answer to your own question? Thats rather odd :)

Comment: Yeah, I think there is a 10 minute timer on accepting answers.